# what does this mean $n\delta$ where $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $\delta \rightarrow 0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup\limits_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \left(n \delta\right)^{-1} \left|T_n(\theta)_{ij}\right| < \infty$ a.s, $1 \leq i \leq p$, $1\leq j \leq p$

what does the multiplication of $n$ and $\delta$ mean, what will happen if one goes to zero and one goes to infinity

Comment: what is the relation between $\delta$ and the limit?

Comment: With so little informations, everything can happen

Comment: There is really not much information available. $T_n$ is a second partial derivative matrix in Taylor expansion and $\theta$ is a point close to a point where the expansion point is and $\delta > 0$ is the radius of the open sphere centered at the point